# Designtime data in mvvmcross service

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I had found this [nice article](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2014/03/20/Coded-Design-Time-Data-using-Mvvmcross-for-Windows-and-Windows-Phone.aspx) (in case anyone would find it useful), but my question is a bit more general. I have a real service, which returns

```
public Task<MobileServiceCollection<ProfileItem, ProfileItem>> PullProfileItems()
    {
        return profileTable.ToCollectionAsync();
    }
```

How can i fill that collection in a designtime service with some fake data?